# Is there any way to keep LG WebOS service alive?

Tags: javascript, webos

I’m trying to create a [JS service](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/js-services/webos-tv-service-basics/) on WebOS 3.0 followed the official documentation.

I can send data between JS service and my application, but sometimes the JS service does not respond to the request if it’s idled for like 20 seconds. I’ve also tried to increase the timeout [per this](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/js-services/js-service-faq/). Unfortunately, it does not seemed to be working.

Here’s my code

**Application Side**

```
const request = webOS.service.request('luna://com.myapp.service', {
        method : 'fetch',
        parameters : { url, method, headers, body },
        onFailure : (err) => {
          reject(err)
        },
        onSuccess : (s) => {
          console.log('request success', s)
        },
        onComplete : (resp) => {
          const isSuccess = resp.data.status >= 200 && resp.data.status < 400
          var payload = {
            json : () => Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(resp.data.body)),
            ok : isSuccess,
            headers : resp.data.headers,
            status : resp.data.status,
            error : isSuccess
              ? null
              : resp.data.body
          }
          resolve(payload)
        }
      })
    })
```

**Service Side**

```
var Service = require('webos-service')
var service = new Service('com.myapp.service')

service.register('fetch', function(message) {
var payload = message.payload
  if(!payload) {
    message.respond({
      returnValue : true,
      error : 'Message does not have a `payload`'
    })
    return
  }
  var url = payload.url,
      headers = payload.headers,
      method = payload.method,
      body = payload.body
  var request = http.request({
    method : method,
    hostname : URL.parse(url).hostname,
    path : URL.parse(url).path,
    headers : headers,
  }, function(res) {
    var data = ''
    res.on('data', function(chunk) { data+=chunk })
    res.on('end', function() {
      message.respond({
        returnValue : true,
        data : {
          status : res.statusCode,
          statusText : res.statusMessage,
          headers : res.headers,
          body : data,
        }
      })
    })
  })
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
    message.respond({
      returnValue : true,
      error : err
    })
  })
  request.end()
})
```

Comment: Are there any errors occurring on the service side?  Is it getting shut down for running too long?  Is the request taking longer than 5 seconds or so?  Difficult for me to parse this code, but I'm not seeing anything obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a JavaScript application for LG Smart-TVs and would highly recommend using *socket.io* for all communication between client and server.
It's a bit tricky getting it to work initially, but works flawlessly.

Here's how the connection looks ...

```
    var socket = io("http://10.27.101.95");
    idUser = getCookie("idUser");   // Retrieved from device and set to cookie.

// ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
// │   Socket.io: Connect/Emit                                      │

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit("addUser", {
            "idUser": idUser
        });
        reconnectHideData = false;
    });

    // Hide data if server cannot be reached.
    var reconnectCount = 0;
    var reconnectHideData = false;
    socket.on('reconnect_error', function() {
        if (reconnectCount < 10 && reconnectHideData == false) {
            // console.log( '---=== Reconnect attempt: ' + reconnectCount + ' ===---' );
            setTimeout(function(){
                reconnectCount++;
            }, 3000);
        }
        if (reconnectCount == 10 && reconnectHideData == false) {
            // console.log( '-----===== Cleared Data =====-----' );
            $('.section ').addClass(' u-hide ');
            $('.greeting').addClass(' u-hide ');
            reconnectHideData = true;
            reconnectCount = 0;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    // Necessary to trigger event to be emitted server side.
    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit("reqData");
    }, 5000);

// └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

After that, it's all a matter of processing and formatting the returned data.

Comment: For communications sent from the TV to the Server, is sockets the only option? Can't something like AJAX be used to send a POST request to the server?

Comment: @nuwanjaya -- Absolutely.  AJAX long-polling works easily enough -- and if it's an application that only a handful of people will be using, then it's a viable option (just avoid short-polling altogether).  
However, websocket is far less demanding on hardware and bandwidth.
Here's an excellent article that explains it in further detail ...
https://blog.baasil.io/why-you-shouldnt-use-long-polling-fallbacks-for-websockets-c1fff32a064a

Comment: To clarify my previous comment ...
This is specific towards displaying real-time data.  If that's not needed, then a simple POST request would be perfectly sufficient.  So, if content is only retrieved when a user clicks a specific button, then AJAX is a fine solution.  
If content is being updated continuously, then websocket is the way to go.  Also, if websocket is implemented for even a single component, then it can easily be used for all requests thereafter.  No need to use them both.

Comment: thank you for the reference article! To give some context to my question, I'm currently testing out how to send a POST from the webOS TV emulator to a localhost server. 
Just to clarify, can the ajax request be sent simply? or is there any prerequisites required, like needing to call some Luna service first and then perform the request?

Comment: @nuwanjaya -- My pleasure.  The WebOS (originally developed by Palm) is essentially a modified, Blink web browser engine (like the one used in Chrome).  The only difference is that it can access TV specific functions (which requires an API library).  When I first started developing for WebOS, I looked into using Enyo and leveraging the Luna service or Mojo.Service API -- but personally found it to be more trouble than it was worth.  So, aside from interacting with a single TV API, I just stick with standard methods (like POST and socket.io) and write everything else (like UI) from scratch.

Comment: Thanks so much! I posted a similar question on the webOS TV forum on their own site and is still to receive any answer whatsoever. Your reply gave a more understandable and logical explanation than any of the stuff I could find on their own docs.
Speaking of webapps,d id you try by any chance to create webapp using different framework than Enyo? Using something like ReactJS?

Comment: @nuwanjaya -- Aside from some of the really old versions of WebOS, just about anything that works in vanilla Chrome should run on the TV with little to no issues.  I haven't used ReactJS personally, but I've leveraged on other JavaScript libraries and have thrown a lot of custom script at it myself.  I even cobbled together this canvas animation to stress test the TV, and it ran it just fine ... https://codepen.io/Mangax/pen/NXXYpY

Comment: The only annoying issue, that I've run across, is anything related to getDate() or getTime() requests.  On a computer, even if it's set to the wrong time, a standard browser uses the current IP location to retrieve the correct time.  The LGs, however, hijack the request and return the current date/time of the TV.  In addition, they don't auto-set their time like a computer or phone -- it will only be auto-set when there's a standard, broadcast signal.  So, if there's no active connection via coaxial cable, it has to be manually set (and it looses a min ever couple of days).

Comment: Glad I could help. :)  I'm in complete agreement with you regarding their documentation and forums.  For the most part, there's very little constructive help to be found online.
I work for an extremely large company and it even took so long to arrange a phone discussion with their developers, by the time it actually took place, (aside from a single question) I had already figured out everything over a month of trial and error.

Comment: @Dustin--you have no idea how much your words mean to me! I've been scouring google hoping to find some "human" semblance of what it is like to actually develop for this platform. Your answers are heaven.

Comment: All that I can gain from this experience is; LGs' webOS TV documentation is a good example of what happens when a non-developer focused company ventures into developer support territory without proper planning.
With a situation like this, won't be long until Android TV overtakes webOS with a better ecosystem simply because of their superior documentation.

Comment: It has been a while, but could you explain in detail how did you get the WebOS JS Service to run socket.io module ?

Comment: @Didzis -- It's essentially a standard web site/application with a few oddities that have to be worked around (most notably, anything beyond JavaScript ES5 won't run on the TV).
The server that hosts the application needs Node.js installed, along with the socket.io module.  The web service is handled by Node.js instead of IIS.  
It's also possible to use IISNode to integrate Node with IIS (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) -- however, I personally found that approach extremely convoluted, so I use PM2 to launch and monitor the Node.js service instead (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).